# Como usar CASE dentro de WHERE en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure, condiciones

tengo la siguiente parte de un procedimiento en sql Server.

```
FROM Personas as p 
  inner join Estados as e on p.EstadoId=e.Id
  inner join ListaMarketing_Persona as lmpe on p.Id=lmpe.IdPersona
  inner join ListaMarketing as lm on lmpe.IdListaMarketing=lm.Id 

where lmpe.IdListaMarketing in (select Id from @Temp_LstMark) 
  and 
    case 
      when @p_EstadoCli<>0 then p.EstadoId = @p_EstadoCli end -- si viene diferente de 0 que compare 
      else p.EstadoId<>69  --si vienen 0 que me traiga todos exceto los de estado 69
      end
```

Actualmente me sale un error en el igual entre `p.EstadoId = @p_EstadoCli` y en la `p` de `p.EstadoId<>69` las dos erroes con el mensaje de **Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de x...** no se cual sea el problema.

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487892/sql-server-case-when-or-then-else-end-the-or-is-not-supported

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Una *expresión* `CASE` es una expresión que devuelve un resultado, no se puede usar como flujo de comparaciones lógicas. Por lo mismo, puedes reescribir tu `CASE` como:

```
where lmpe.IdListaMarketing in (select Id from @Temp_LstMark) 
  and 
    case 
      when p.EstadoId = @p_EstadoCli 
      then 1
      when @p_EstadoCli = 0 AND p.EstadoId <> 69  then 1
      else 0
      end = 1
```

Comment: El objetivo es que cuando llegue un valor a `@p_EstadoCli` traiga solo lo registro con ese Estado, si viene cero que es lo otro me traiga a todos exepto los de estado 69(nunca debe traer los de estado 69)

Comment: @VitmarAliaga ok, actualicé mi respuesta